# Escape response in karate framework

Tags: karate

When I pass response from feature file into Java method , url present in one of the json object is automatically getting converted. How to avoid this conversion

e.g.

"url": "https://abc.xyz.com/blog/post/best-haircuts-for-kids",

is getting converted to

https:\//abc.xyz.com\/blog\/post\/best-haircuts-for-kids